# Well liked: passive vs adjective

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, participial-adjectives

> You use **well** to emphasize some -*ed* participles when they are
> part of a passive construction, *you seem to be **well liked** at
> work.*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/well

> Well-liked adj (**well liked** when postpositive) liked by many
> people; popular
>
> https://www.thefreedictionary.com/well-liked

What makes **well liked** a passive, instead of an adjective, in the first example?

Comment: Well-liked is an adjective here. Passive voice requires subject and object to switch their usual places -- tell me, what is the object in the sentence?

Comment: @FeliniusRex, Passive requires that the subject is not the agent of the main verb. There is no "switching". "You seem to be well liked (by your co-workers)" is quite clearly a passive construction.

Comment: @gotube You are reading it as a passive construction, because you are assuming you need an inferred object. I do not see a need for any object, because the statement works as is. "You seem to be well-liked at work" is no more passive than "You seem to be popular at work" or "You seem to be distinguished at work." I've told you before to not be a jerk. I repeat myself here.

Comment: @FeliniusRex, Wow, that's totally unnecessary and uncalled for. You can't see the difference between me disagreeing with you (rightly or wrongly) and me trying to upset you somehow. You can stop it now with the personal attacks.

Comment: @gotube This was not intended as a personal attack but as me trying to point out that the way you expressed it allowed no room for disagreement. I should have said that instead. I apologize.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Fair enough. I apologize too